Difficulty in understanding the difference between division and distribution in combinatorics
In elementary combinatorics, I read a paragraph from a book on division of $n$ objects into $r$ groups so with the first having $x_1, x_2, x_3,\ldots,x_r$ so we are generally given this formula for the said operation of 'Division' that is
$$
\frac{n!}{x_1!\,x_2!\,\ldots\, x_r!}
$$
Then it gives me the formula of distribution of said objects
$$
\frac{n!}{x_1!\,x_2!\,\ldots\,x_r!} \times r!
$$

There wasn't any further explanation given on the same, so from what I can decipher, the fact is that for distribution, you just need to mix the groups among themselves, like that order of getting those $n$ things divided amongst the groups and then arranging the groups amongst themselves.

Please help in the same and correct me if I was wrong because this is what I can understand am I correct in understanding this ?.

In the first formula, the groups are in a particular order, whereas in the second formula, all possible orders are taken into account. However, I don't quite like the terminology adopted.  The normal terminology for the first/second types is ordered/unordered groups.

@trueblueanil thanks actually the book I am using is using the same terminology probably that is why I was confused sorta but hey thanks for helping out

You're wrlcome !
